# FFMPEG Frame to DirectX Surface Hardware Accelerated

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, directx-9, hardware-acceleration

I use ffmpeg functions to decode h264 frames and display in a window on windows platform. The approach which I use is as below (from [FFMPEG Frame to DirectX Surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321298/ffmpeg-frame-to-directx-surface/408331#408331)):

```
AVFrame *frame;
avcodec_decode_video(_ffcontext, frame, etc...);

lockYourSurface();
uint8_t *buf = getPointerToYourSurfacePixels();

// Create an AVPicture structure which contains a pointer to the RGB surface.
AVPicture pict;

memset(&pict, 0, sizeof(pict));

avpicture_fill(&pict, buf, PIX_FMT_RGB32,
               _ffcontext->width, _ffcontext->height);



// Convert the image into RGB and copy to the surface.
img_convert(&pict, PIX_FMT_RGB32, (AVPicture *)frame,
            _context->pix_fmt, _context->width, _context->height);


unlockYourSurface();
```

In the code, I use sws_scale instead of img_convert.

When I pass the surface data pointer to sws_scale (in fact in avpicture_fill), it seems that the data pointer is actually on RAM not on GPU memory, and when I want to display the surface, it seems that the data is moved to GPU and then displayed. As I know CPU utilization is high when data is copied between RAM and GPU memory.

How I can tel ffmpeg to render directly to a surface on GPU memory (not a data pointer on RAM)?

Comment: If the data pointer is in RAM, is that not because of the getPointerToYourSurfacePixels() function, meaning ffmpeg cannot change anything about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this problem. To prevent extra cpu usage in displaying frames using ffmpeg, we must not decode the frame to RGB. Almost all of the video files are decoded to YUV (this is the original image format inside the video file). The point here is that GPU is able to display YUV data directly without need to convert it to RGB. As I know, using ffmpeg usual version, decoded data is always on RAM. For a frame, the amount of YUV data is very small as compared to RGB decoded equivalent of the same frame. So when we move YUV data to GPU instead of converting to RGB and then moving to GPU, we speed up operation from two sides:

1. No conversion to RGB
2. Amount of data moved between RAM and GPU is decreased

So finally the overall CPU usage is decreased.

Comment: @M.Mahidpour Is there any example you can point to take a look what you have proposed?

Comment: @AJit You can find information on it. Graphic cards have ability to display YUV data (and also some other formats which are mostly used in 3D games). And also it is known that moving data between CPU and GPU is a heavy process, so most GPU based algorithms allow keep result in GPU for further processing (e.g. CUDA).